# How can I convert DVDs to be playable on my iPod?

Tags: video, itunes, dvd, conversion, ipod

I can convert my CDs to a suitable format, and put these onto my iPod Nano 4th Gen. However is there a way of converting DVDs to a suitable format and thus putting my DVDs on there too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, before ripping any DVD to be used on your iPod, please make sure that you are legally entitled to do so. Most commercial DVDs sold in the US (and abroad) have copy restrictions which are illegal under the DMCA to circumvent, sometimes *even in cases of fair use*.

That being said, if you are legally permitted to do so, [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) works well for ripping DVDs and converting them to a format compatible with iPods. It has presets for the iPod format and other popular formats. It is free, open-source software, and has worked well for me in the past.

Comment: +1 for Handbrake. There is also a command line option called "handbrakecli" included in the installer which you can also use to automate the process. Well, automate the process as much as you can considering you still need to manually put in and take out the DVD.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [Super ©](http://www.erightsoft.com/S6Kg1.html) for ages now, if virtually converts anything into anything. Including DVD-VOB files to iPod playable files. It even comes with iPod presets to convert the DVD as efficiently as possible. I love using it!